# Views and Blocks translation

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-9

I tried to translate views and block with two new languages on a website (there are 6 others languages who work perfectly).
When I tried to translate views or blocks with theses two new languages, I have this message : "English, Canada translation was not added. To add a translation, you must modify the configuration."
Translation of node and terms works fine. I don't understand what I'm suppose to do.
I saw nothing to set on languages's settings page.
Anyone already had this issue ?

I saw a ticket on drupal.org which talk about increase the max_input_vars in php.ini. It doesn't work for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For add translation of view require change of the configuration , without change it does not work .

you can see this example :
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2488302